# How can I know the type of secret returned from Barbican GET /v1/secrets/ call?

Tags: openstack, kmip

I want to know the type of the key returned i.e, SYMMETRIC/PUBLIC/PRIVATE etc.
I have referred to [Barbican API doc](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/barbican/api.html) and came to know that the type parameter is used to know the secret type. But this parameter is only available in response to `GET v1/orders/{order_id}` call. Such parameter is not there in `GET /v1/secrets/` call.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter called `secret_type` which returns the type of secret returned. Supported values for this parameter are:

- symmetric
- public
- private
- passphrase
- certificate
- opaque

`opaque` is used as the default, which is used to signal Barbican to just store the information without worrying about format or encoding.

REFERENCE: [API](https://github.com/cloudkeep/barbican/wiki/Application-Programming-Interface#secrets-resource)